# How to specify a specific day and time when adding calendar event programmatically

Tags: iphone, nsdate, icalendar, eventkit

I am trying to programatically add an event into the default calendar but can not find how I set the time at which the event takes place, and the duration of the event. All I have accomplished so far by following a number of different tutorials is to create an all day event which reoccurs every day. The code I have so far is below.

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

    EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];


    // use this in the method that actually creates the event
    NSError *err = nil;
    //This date will be the date our reminder expires, as in stops recurring.  Two years was chosen as most users
    //will replace their device after 2 years
    NSDate *fourteenWeeksFromNow = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:8467200];
    //Define the recurrance rule
    EKRecurrenceRule *recurrance;
    NSDateComponents *comp = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];


    [comp setYear:0];
    [comp setMonth:0];
    [comp setDay:7]; 
    //Recurr every 7 days I think but not working
    recurrance = [[EKRecurrenceRule alloc] initRecurrenceWithFrequency:EKRecurrenceFrequencyWeekly interval:1 end:[EKRecurrenceEnd recurrenceEndWithEndDate:fourteenWeeksFromNow]];

    NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    //Our remind date
    NSDate *eventDate = [cal dateByAddingComponents:comp toDate:[NSDate date] options:0]; // unsure what this does or how to use it


    double alarmAmountInSeconds = 60.0*60.0*0.25; // 15 mins
    EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:(-1.0*alarmAmountInSeconds)]; // this is working correctly, alerts 15 minutes before

    NSMutableArray *alarmsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [alarmsArray addObject:alarm];


    [recurrenceRules arrayByAddingObject:recurrance];

    event.title = module;

    event.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init]; //  works
    event.endDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:8467200 sinceDate:event.startDate]; // works

    event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents; // works
    event.title = module; // works
    event.allDay = FALSE; // dont want it all day but need to be able find out how to set time
    event.location = @"Test location"; 
    event.alarms = alarmsArray; // works
    event.recurrenceRules = recurrenceRules; // not working could be problems with other attributes though
    event.notes = @"This is a test"; // works


    // Try to save the event
    [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanFutureEvents error:&err];
```

Comment: Still not getting which line are you getting problems in date

Comment: This is a mix of code I have used from a tutorial. I don't know how to get the event to occur at a specific day or time. This occurs all day everyday.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed that documentations??
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Have you seen sample code of apple??
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleEKDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010160

In this line you can set the time 
event.startDate = your time with date object.

Comment: I have followed the documentation and it I can't find anywhere which says how to set it for a specific time. The recurrence rule section in the documentation seems to most relevant but I still can't figure out the time aspect.

The sample code from Apple in that link or retrieve events from the calendar I think?

Apologies for my lack of know how I am normally ok at using the documentation however this time I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake I was making was not how I was thinking about the classes and the class names. Seems stupid I know. Everything is done with start and end date and I expect to see more attributes to set the exact time. But now I see that this is done through getting the right amount of seconds and using NSDate.